# Push notifications progressive web app on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I need to develop a progressive web app with push notifications integrated. Searching on the web I have found diverse opinions about this subject.
If I have understood correctly, for now, we cannot have push notifications in safari for mobile (but only for Desktop). Is it right?

Do you have any suggestions to obtain the same result (I am not an iOS expert)? I was wondering that maybe developing a native app only for push notifications purposes could be a good choice until push notification will be ready also for safari mobile.

P.S. I am developing the PWA using Angular 2.

Thank you for the support.

Comment: Only native apps on iOS can register for push notifications

Comment: for now iOS does not support native push notifications. The best alternative I have is to fall back to SMS. You can feature detect if push is supported and display a different opt-in UI for SMS.
When Apple joins everyone else then your pages will just naturally allow push notification opt-in.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, based [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58210428/2671470) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49803408/2671470) the latest iOS version(13.3)  still doesn't support some features of progressive web app:

- Web Push Notification
- Background Sync
- Page Lifecycle
- Service Workers on WebViews
- Universal Links / Link Capturing

Until now, no news that says will be implemented on the next version 14. As I said in the old post, I think iOS doesn't want to support these in PWA because these features have a bigger chance to be unnecessary exploited(spam, etc). And also maybe they want to force developers to create the native application rather than the progressive web application.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to let you know: Apple will support push notifications for web apps! This news was published at the WWDC2022. Apple will release Web Push with Safari 16 on macOS (Ventura) in a few months (2022) and for iOS and iPadOS in 2023.

See: https://webkit.org/blog/12945/meet-web-push/

Until this is working, I will use this [Flutter wrapper](https://github.com/bettysteger/flutter_pwa_wrapper) thats embeds the PWA in a Webview.