# iOS/iPadOS safari push api support

Tags: ios, webkit, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, ipados

Does the iOS/iPadOS version of safari support push api standard with service worker?

Comment: This is insane that Apple doesn't allow this yet - they should make it an option for owners of Apple devices (it could even be defaulted to disabled - but it should be available.) Sign the petition on Change.org - search Web Push. https://www.change.org/p/tim-cook-apple-inc-implement-web-push-notifications-on-ios-devices

Comment: I've added the link to the petition on the question, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As for 2023, IOS 16 will support web push notification. That is announced on their official blog:

https://webkit.org/blog/13878/web-push-for-web-apps-on-ios-and-ipados/

But it seems only web apps that have been added to the Home Screen can request permission to send push notifications.

old answer:

iOS 12, 13, and iOS/iPadOS 14 still doesn't support these features:

- Web Push Notification
- Background Sync
- Page Lifecycle
- Service Workers on WebViews
- Universal Links / Link Capturing

So many requests from the community for these features but Apple don't want to hear it. Maybe they think these features have a bigger chance to be unnecessary exploited(spam, etc). And also maybe they want to force developers to create the native application rather than the progressive web application.

Comment: iOS wants to get iE place

Comment: local web notifications api isn't supported either - ie https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Answer (score 14):

iOS don't support the W3C Spec web push notifications yet. But there is a Safari specific API for web notifications. Refer to this answer on multiple options you have.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49803408/1057093

**Update:** Corrected the Answer in the above link to clarify  proprietary solution is only for OS X - Safari and no solution for iOS Safari yet. Custom in app notification is the best we can do today for iOS Safari.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I searched on the documentation and this feature is only for OS and not for iOS. Have you implemented successfully safari push notifications somewhere and checked with iOS safari? Because I can't find anything usefull.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I've updated both the answer for better clarity. Yes. iOS-Safari don't support both the web notification APIs and in app notification is the only option we have for now. We like it or not, that's the limitation for now.

Answer (score 7):

I tested iOS 12 in beta last week and as Anand said, there is no change about this functionnality and more globally for Progressive Web App because the Web Manifest, in developpement at this moment is not implemented yet.

Comment: Has anyone got the chance to test iOS 13 beta ?

Comment: There are new features for pwa but nothing about push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 15.4 added a **Push API** feature in safari

**Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental WebKitFeatures**

but it is turned off by default.

That doesn't mean the Web Push Notification is fully supported in iOS but it is a hint that it might be coming soon.
Hopefully iOS 16

Comment: just saw https://www.theapplepost.com/2022/06/06/ios-16-to-support-web-push-notifications-beginning-next-year/

Answer (score 0):

It still doesn't, but it was just announced that it's coming in 2023.

Source: https://webkit.org/blog/12824/news-from-wwdc-webkit-features-in-safari-16-beta/

(It's at the bottom of the "*Web Push for macOS*
" section)