# ios 12 PWA web push notifications. Does it work?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

I am not able to find a way to enable web push notifications for a PWA app. Does that work in IOS like it does on android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692775/ios-12-web-push-notifications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 12 web push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692775/ios-12-web-push-notifications)

Comment: @TamásSengel your comment is also a possible duplication of the above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** the web push api is not yet available on the iOS yet (as of May 2019)

refer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager