# Does service worker live in background on ios safari? Can it fetch data on background?

Tags: ios, cordova, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, phonegap-plugin-push

Is service worker registered by my app active in background on ios/safari as it is on android/chrome?

If so, is it able to receive message from notification handled by `phonegap-plugin-push`?

Our scenario is: run app, register SW, exit app, receive notification, fetch new data on background in SW, go offline, open app and see fetched data. Is it even possible on ios with cordova and push plugin?

Edit: I already know that we need our app to be wrapped inside cordova with `phonegap-plugin-push` as on iOS push notifications are not supported for PWA. My question was whether the SW live on background same as in case of chrome/android. I suppose not, because even on chrome/android the SW is active only due to waiting for push notifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 12 web push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692775/ios-12-web-push-notifications)

Comment: iOS does not support push notifications.