# PWA push notification support iOS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am Making React PWA (progressive web app) app  but i have no idea push notification in iOS work properly or not please suggest me anyone make before PWA app. Its good idea or not.

Answer (score 4):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50347859/push-notifications-progressive-web-app-on-ios), only native apps on iOS can register for push notifications. Also from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49803408/5832311):

> While [iOS don't support Web Push notifications yet](https://caniuse.com/#search=notification)(as of Apr-2018), all you can do is have an event listener for data from server side(Firebase in your case) and receive that data to show it as an Notification/alert or how ever you want to present inside your application(not in iOS notification area).
>
> Unfortunately, this is the best way you can handle notifications for iOS. I know, its not so great for developers :) Hope Apple speeds up on PWA. They are more than a year late to Service worker party itself. What to expect!